# Get a drop-down menu to work inside/outside of a hamburger menu

Tags: javascript, html, mobile, drop-down-menu, hamburger-menu

I want to get the Language menu to work as a drop-down menu when it's on desktop and remain an inactive drop-down menu when it's on mobile.

Once clicked on mobile it should show the options inside the drop-down menu, remaining inside the hamburger menu.

Language menu:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/bik75.png

&&

https://i.stack.imgur.com/waYAk.png

What I want it to do on desktop:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/OD5zn.png

I have made the menu clickable on desktop with javascript code, but on mobile the menu acts weirdly.

I would like to see the drop-down menu work when clicked on desktop, and when I click anywhere else on the desktop it would close, not just when I click the menu itself.

On mobile the menu appears weirdly instead of being deactivated until clicked.

**JSFiddle ->** `<script async src="//jsfiddle.net/jkuwg3ac/embed/"></script>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a better way to create a language menu using **Bulma** without **JavaScript**.

Language menu **HTML**:

```
<div class="select">
  <select>
    <option selected>English</option>
    <option>Italian</option>
    <option>Arabic</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Here is your project using my idea:

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {

  // Get all "navbar-burger" elements
  const $navbarBurgers = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.navbar-burger'), 0);

  // Check if there are any navbar burgers
  if ($navbarBurgers.length > 0) {

    // Add a click event on each of them
    $navbarBurgers.forEach(el => {
      el.addEventListener('click', () => {

        // Get the target from the "data-target" attribute
        const target = el.dataset.target;
        const $target = document.getElementById(target);

        // Toggle the "is-active" class on both the "navbar-burger" and the "navbar-menu"
        el.classList.toggle('is-active');
        $target.classList.toggle('is-active');

      });
    });
  }

});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Test!</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bulma/0.7.4/css/bulma.min.css">
  <script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.3.1/js/all.js"></script>
</head>

<body>


  <nav class="navbar has-text-centered" role="navigation" aria-label="main navigation">
    <div class="navbar-brand">
      <a class="navbar-item" href="https://bulma.io">
        <img src="https://bulma.io/images/bulma-logo.png" width="112" height="28">
      </a>

      <a role="button" class="navbar-burger" aria-label="menu" aria-expanded="false" data-target="navMenu">
        <span aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span aria-hidden="true"></span>
      </a>
    </div>

    <div id="navMenu" class="navbar-menu">
      <div class="navbar-start">
        <a class="navbar-item">
            Home
          </a>

        <a class="navbar-item">
            Documentation
          </a>

      </div>

      <div class="navbar-end">
        <div class="select">
          <select>
            <option selected>English</option>
            <option>Italian</option>
            <option>Arabic</option>
          </select>
        </div>

      </div>


    </div>
  </nav>

</body>

</html>
```